# How to display placeholder's text in HTML5's number-typed input

Tags: html, input, placeholder

Is there a way I can show placeholder text inside an input tag of type=number?

Detailed Q:
The property 'placeholder' of an HTML's input tag is used to show description about the input tag in the UI when the element is not focused - the descriptive text goes blank when the same field gets focus. The problem is no text is visible if the input type is made of type="number". I do have space limitations in my UI and cannot afford a label before the input tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute): *The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format.* It isn't a replacement for `<label>`.

Comment: placeholder text doesn't seem to work in IE browser

Answer (score 30):

Placeholders aren't intended as labels for input. Placeholder should contain examples of valid input. So in case of a number input the only valid value for placeholder is a number.

But if you want to misuse the placeholder to save room you could just use a little JS to fix your problem.

```
<input placeholder="Amount" onfocus="this.type='number';">
```

PS Chrome Nightly seems to have no problem with combining number and placeholder.

Comment: @BugWhisperer you can also use `inputmode="decimal"` if you only want to make mobile phones show the numeric keyboard.

Comment: no longer works, but there are other workarounds like placing an element with `position:absolute` inside a container with `position:relative` and an `input` element

Comment: i didnt even know about `inputmode`. it has fairly wide support too.

Comment: @BugWhisperer Could you tell which browser it doesn't work on. I just tested inputs with placeholders, and with my `onfocus` trick, and both seem to work fine in IE11, Chrome and Firefox.