# Placeholder text for an input type="number" does not show in webkit ICS

Tags: android, html

I have the following input field

```
<input type="number" id="zip-code" placeholder="Zip code" />
```

Placeholder is shown in normal browsers except android 4.0 and above and the width also get reduced compared to other fields.
What could be the error?

Answer (score 21):

It's a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24626) in the default Android Webkit browser. As per [this QuirksMode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html), you can see that many versions of Android suffer from this. Chrome for Android on the other hand, doesn't.

I've created a simple JavaScript shim (fix) for this. First, read this question [How to display placeholder's text in HTML5's number-typed input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401495/how-to-display-placeholders-text-in-html5s-number-typed-input), then if you still want to use a placeholder like that, checkout [my solution gist](https://gist.github.com/3786176).

TL;DR;

Leave your markup as you would expect;

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter some numbers" />
```

Then run either of these scripts after the page has loaded;

```
// jQuery version
$("input[type='number']").each(function(i, el) {
    el.type = "text";
    el.onfocus = function(){this.type="number";};
    el.onblur = function(){this.type="text";};
});

// Stand-alone version
(function(){ var elms = document.querySelectorAll("input"), i=elms.length;
    while(i--) {
        var el=elms[i]; if(el.type=="number"])
            el.type="text",
            el.onfocus = function(){this.type="number";},
            el.onblur = function(){this.type="text";};
    }
})();
```

Comment: Under Jellybean this solution only works part of the time, leading to missing keyboards in response to the user's tap. Running this code in capturing mode seemed to smooth out a lot of these issues.

Comment: @KevinDecker Thanks for testing it - can you explain what you mean capturing mode?

Comment: is it possible that on Android 2.3 it doesnt work,  but it works on later versions?  Thanks

Comment: @aaronsnoswell You can adjust this to make it valid in W3C validator just by actually loading the page from the server initially with `type=text` with an identifier like `data-typenumber`, and then applying the event listeners (onfocus, onblur) directly to `input[data-typenumber]` inputs...

Answer (score 11):

By using type = "tel' instead of type = "number" the placeholder is displayed and the numeric keyboard is opened on focus.

Comment: Tel would work for US only but is not appropriate for international postal codes that require alhpa-numeric characters.

Comment: In the specific context of this question, @TaeKwonJoe is right. But in general, this is by far the best solution for the question's title: 'Placeholder text for an input type=“number” does not show in webkit'. After all, the title doesn't specify the problem is `zip-code` related.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was setting the 'type' field as text. I think it happens because of the type property. Your placeholder text is not a number! If you have to force user to use only number format, you may use javascript plugins for this and i did it like that :)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" id="zip-code" placeholder="Zip code">
```

Comment: Please do not use *try this* as answer. explain what you have done and why.