# input type text wrong placeholder value

Tags: android, html

I have this input field

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text..." id="adddress" maxlength="80"/>
```

However, It shows an email adress I entered with the phone on a different site, which is weird behaviour.

I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24626) google troubleshoot and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576226/placeholder-text-for-an-input-type-number-does-not-show-in-webkit-ics) here on stackoverflow. But both seem to have the issue with type="number". I changed the input field to this.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.type='number'" onblur="this.type='text'" placeholder="placeholder text"/>
```

but it doesnt work. It only happens in Android 4.x. Anybody experienced similar and has any tipps for me?

Comment: Is your question specific to Android? If so, could you tag your question accordingly?

Comment: the issue seems to be solved, I deleted the formular data on the phone, and it shows the correct placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone has the same problem:

```
Delete the formula data on the phone. (Adnroid 4.x Stock Browser.), it seems to solve the problem.
```

Comment: what do you mean by formula data, i have the same problem.

Comment: pardon me, I meant the form data. You can delete it from the browser settings.