# How to force numeric keyboard for ZipCode and Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: android, ios, html

I have read through several answers on stackoverflow which do not solve the issue for displaying a numeric keyboard for a Samsung Galaxy for Zip Code.

iOS will bring up a numeric keyboard but Samsung Galaxy will not bring up a numeric keyboard for this code:

```
<input name="zipCode" type="text" pattern="\d*" required="required" title="Please enter a valid U.S. zip code">
```

The HTML5 Number Input Type will not work because it truncates zip codes that start with zeros:

```
<input name="zipCode" type="number" required="required" min="0" title="Please enter a valid U.S. zip code">
```

This does not work for iOS or Samsung Galaxy as iOS looks for [0-9]* or \d* for the pattern:

```
<input name="zipCode" type="text" pattern="^\d{5}$" required="required" title="Please enter a valid U.S. zip code">
```

Comment: IceCreamSandwich? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12594528/603270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe tel numbers might work. Try:

`<input type="tel" />`

Comment: The final solution that I am going to use is this:
<input name="zipCode" type="tel" pattern="^\d{5}$" required="required" title="Please enter a valid U.S. zip code">